# How to compare the inputs of two entries using single tkinter function for a bunch of such pairs of entries?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want to validate two tkinter entries. One called minimum and the other called maximum. Of course, I want to make sure that minimum does not exceed maximum. And there is a third entry called increment which has to be lesser than maximum. There are a set of 15 such entries which I am trying to validate.

I have tried using for loop and tracing the textvariable of each entry. But inside the for loop, I am able to validate only a single entry box. Also, when I skip the validation for that specific one entry called the txtCab, it throws the following exception: If I do it for all the widgets, it does work, but fails some times.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\beejb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\PROSAIL_5B_Fortran\PROSAIL_5B_FORTRAN\PROSAIL.py", line 191, in min_max
    minVar = eval("self.txtVar_"+ str(wid)+ "_min.get()")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

The validation function I have used is:

```
def min_max(*args):
            alltextFields = ["N","Cab","Car","Cw","Cm","Cbrown", "rsoil0","LIDFa","LIDFb","TypeLIDF","LAI","hspot","tts","tto","psi" ]
            for wid in alltextFields:
                if eval("self." + wid + "_variable.get()"):
                    minVar = eval("self.txtVar_"+ str(wid)+ "_min.get()")
                    maxVar = eval("self.txtVar_"+ str(wid) + "_max.get()")
                    rangeVar = eval("self.txtVar_"+ str(wid) + "_range.get()")
##
##            print((minVar))
##            print((maxVar))
##            print((rangeVar))

            if len(minVar) > 0 and len(maxVar):
                if (minVar) > (maxVar):
                    messagebox.showinfo("Input Error", "Minimum should not be greater than maximum")

            if len(rangeVar) > 0 and len(maxVar) > 0:
                if (rangeVar) > (maxVar) :
                    messagebox.showinfo("Input Error", "Increment cannot exceed maximum limit")

##            print(self.txtVar_Cab_min.get()); print(self.txtVar_Cab_max.get());
##            print(self.txtVar_N_min.get()); print(self.txtVar_N_max.get());
            if len(self.txtVar_Cab_min.get()) > 0 and len(self.txtVar_Cab_max.get()) > 0 and len(self.txtVar_Cab_range.get()) > 0:
                if (self.txtVar_Cab_min.get()) > (self.txtVar_Cab_max.get()):
                    messagebox.showinfo("Input Data Error", "Minimum should not be greater than maximum!!")
                if (self.txtVar_Cab_range.get()) > (self.txtVar_Cab_max.get()):
                    messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Increment cannot exceed maximum!!")
```

Another validation function I have tried is:

```
    def validateMRM(self,value, text,W):
        vMin,vMax,vRange;
        entry = self.controller.nametowidget(W)
        print(entry)
        if entry == self.txt_N_min:
            print(entry.get())
            print(self.txtVar_N_max.get())
            print(self.txtVar_N_range.get())
        alltextFields = ["txt_N","txt_Cab","txt_Car","txt_Cab","txt_Cw","txt_Cw","txt_Cm","txt_Cbrown","txt_Cm", "txt_rsoil0",
                                    "txt_LIDFa","txt_LIDFb","txt_TypeLIDF","txt_LAI","txt_hspot","txt_hspot","txt_tts","txt_tto","txt_psi"
                                ]
        for wid in alltextFields:
            typeOfVar = wid.split("_")

            if entry == eval("self.txt_" + str(typeOfVar[1])+ "_min"):
                vMin = eval("self.txtVar_" + str(typeOfVar[1])+ "_min.get()")
                print(eval("self.txtVar_" + str(typeOfVar[1])+ "_min.get()"))
                vMax = eval("self.txtVar_" + str(typeOfVar[1])+ "_max.get()")
                print(eval("self.txtVar_" + str(typeOfVar[1])+ "_max.get()"))
                vRange = eval("self.txtVar_" + str(typeOfVar[1])+ "_range.get()")
                print(eval("self.txtVar_" + str(typeOfVar[1])+ "_range.get()"))

        print(vMin); print(vMax); print(vRange)

        if len(vMin) > 0 and len(vMax) > 0 and len(vRange) > 0:
            if (vMin) > (vMax):
                messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Minimum cannot be greater than maximum")
            if (vRange) > (vMax) :
                messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Increment cannot exceed the maximum limit")        
        print(len(entry.get()))
        if len(entry.get())>2:
```

And here is how all the entries are created:

```
 self.lbl_N = tk.Label(self,text="Structure Coefficient(N)",anchor="w",width=40,bg='white'); self.lbl_N.grid(row=3,column=4,padx=4,pady=4);
        self.N_variable = tk.BooleanVar()
        self.chk_N = tk.Checkbutton(self,variable=self.N_variable, command=lambda:self.show_hide()); self.chk_N.grid(row=3,column=6,padx=4,pady=4);
        self.txt_N = tk.Entry(self,width=10,validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd); self.txt_N.grid(row=3,column=7,padx=4,pady=4);

        self.txtVar_N_min = tk.StringVar(); self.txtVar_N_max = tk.StringVar(); self.txtVar_N_range = tk.StringVar();
        self.txtVar_N_min.trace("w", min_max); self.txtVar_N_max.trace("w", min_max); self.txtVar_N_range.trace("w", min_max);

        self.txt_N_min = tk.Entry(self,width=5,validate = 'key',textvariable=self.txtVar_N_min, validatecommand = vcmd_min_max);
        self.txt_N_max = tk.Entry(self,width=5,validate = 'key', textvariable=self.txtVar_N_max,validatecommand = vcmd_min_max);
        self.txt_N_range = tk.Entry(self,width=5,validate = 'key', textvariable=self.txtVar_N_range,validatecommand = vcmd_min_max);
```

There are a set of fourteen such entries and I need to validate each of them.

But none of this gives the actual output I want. It works some time and fails some other times.
I am not sure why is that happening and I have spent a hell of time with this validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this answers your question but it should point you in the right direction.

I couldn't make much sense of your code.  I've produced a 15 row x 4 column grid.
The 4th column is a message that the 3 fields next to it are 'OK' or if not indicate the problem.  The validation is run on the whole grid for each keypress.  If this is too slow a validate button could launch the validation instead.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def rec(): return {'lo': 0, 'hi': 0, 'step': 0, 'ok': '' }

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('SO Question')

def entry(id, ent_dict, var_dict, v=0):
    """ Add an Entry Widget to the root, with associated StringVar."""
    var_dict[id] = tk.StringVar()
    var_dict[id].set(str(v))
    ent_dict[id] = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable= var_dict[id], width = 10 )
    return ent_dict[id]

def do_validate(lo, hi, step):
    """ Return OK if lo, hi and step are consistent else an error string. """
    if lo < hi and step < hi: return 'OK'
    txt = ''
    if lo >= hi: 
        txt = 'lo >= hi. ' 
    if step >= hi:
        txt += 'step >= hi.'
    return txt 

def conv(txt):
    """ Convert text to float.  Return 0.0 if not valid float e.g "" or 'a' """
    try: 
        return float(txt)
    except ValueError:
        return 0.0 

def oklabel(ent_dict, var_dict):
    """ Add an OK Label to a row. """
    lo = conv(var_dict['lo'].get())
    hi = conv(var_dict['hi'].get())
    step = conv(var_dict['step'].get())
    var_dict['ok'] = tk.StringVar()
    var_dict['ok'].set(do_validate(lo, hi, step))
    ent_dict['ok'] = ttk.Label(root, textvariable = var_dict['ok'], width = -17)
    return ent_dict['ok']  # Return the Label object for gridding. 

def do_check(*args):
    """ Loop through the rows setting the validation string in each one. """ 
    for var_dict in stringvars:
        lo = conv(var_dict['lo'].get())
        hi = conv(var_dict['hi'].get())
        step = conv(var_dict['step'].get())
        var_dict['ok'].set(do_validate(lo, hi, step))

# Add column labels
ttk.Label(root, text='Minimums').grid(row=0, column=0)
ttk.Label(root, text =' Maximums').grid(row=0, column=1)
ttk.Label(root, text='Increment').grid(row=0, column=2)
ttk.Label(root, text='Valid').grid(row=0, column=3)

# Create containers for he Entries and Stringvars
entries =[]
stringvars = []

# Add 15 rows of Entries / Validation Labels to the UI. 
for row in range(1, 16):
    tempe=rec()
    tempv=rec()       
    entry('lo', tempe, tempv, 0).grid(row = row, column=0)
    entry('hi', tempe, tempv, 0).grid(row = row, column=1)
    entry('step', tempe, tempv, 0).grid(row = row, column=2)
    oklabel(tempe, tempv).grid(row = row, column = 3)
    entries.append(tempe)
    stringvars.append(tempv)

# Bind do_check to all Entry widgets.
root.bind_class('TEntry', '<KeyPress>', do_check, add='+')
root.bind_class('TEntry', '<BackSpace>', do_check, add='+')
root.bind_class('TEntry', '<Delete>', do_check, add='+')

root.mainloop()
```

In the past I've got stuck trying to validate multiple fields by not allowing inconsistent entries.  It is difficult for users to follow what is required to correct fields.  They have to work in the correct order.  e.g. lo = 100, hi = 9, and step = 1.  Should the UI allow the last zero in 100 to be deleted, leaving 10 which is gt 9?

This could be extended to activate a 'Next' button only if all rows are OK.

**Edit 1 - Response to Comment**

This has a function to create and activate each row of the display.  Each row has it's own variables and checking function.  They are triggered by the trace on the three Entry StringVars, there's no need to use validate.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def to_float(txt):
    """ Safely convert any string to a float.  Invalid strings return 0.0 """ 
    try:
        return float(txt)
    except ValueError: 
        return 0.0

def row_n( parent, n, init_show = 0 ):
    """ Create one row of the display. """
    # tk.Variables
    v_show = tk.IntVar()
    v_min = tk.StringVar()
    v_max = tk.StringVar()
    v_incr = tk.StringVar()
    v_message = tk.StringVar()

    # Initialise variables
    v_min.set('0')
    v_max.set('1')
    v_incr.set('1')  # Can the increment be zero?
    v_show.set(init_show)
    v_message.set("OK")

    def do_trace(*args):
        """ Runs every time any of the three Entries change value. 
            Sets the message to the appropriate text.
        """
        lo = to_float(v_min.get())
        hi = to_float(v_max.get())
        inc = to_float(v_incr.get())
        if lo < hi and inc <=hi:
            v_message.set('OK')
        else:
            txt = ''
            if lo >= hi: 
                txt += 'Min >= Max'
            if inc > hi:
                if len(txt): txt += ' & '
                txt += 'Incr > Max'
            v_message.set(txt)

    # Set trace callback for changes to the three StringVars
    v_min.trace('w', do_trace)
    v_max.trace('w', do_trace)
    v_incr.trace('w', do_trace)

    def activation(*args):
        """ Runs when the tickbox changes state """
        if v_show.get():
            e_min.grid(row = n, column = 1)
            e_max.grid(row = n, column = 2)
            e_inc.grid(row = n, column = 3)
            message.grid(row = n, column = 4)
        else:
            e_min.grid_remove()
            e_max.grid_remove()
            e_inc.grid_remove()
            message.grid_remove()

    tk.Checkbutton(parent, 
        text = 'Structure Coefficient {} :'.format(n), 
        variable = v_show, command = activation ).grid(row = n, column = 0)
    e_min = tk.Entry(parent, width=5, textvariable = v_min)
    e_max =tk.Entry(parent, width=5, textvariable = v_max)
    e_inc = tk.Entry(parent, width=5, textvariable = v_incr)
    message = tk.Label(parent, width=-15, textvariable = v_message)
    activation()

    return { 'Min': v_min, 'Max': v_max, 'Inc': v_incr }

def show_results():
    print('Min   Max  Inc')
    for row in rows:
        res = '{}   {}  {}'.format(row['Min'].get(), row['Max'].get(), row['Inc'].get())
        print( res )

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('SO Question')

ttk.Label(root, text='Minimums').grid(row=0, column=1)
ttk.Label(root, text =' Maximums').grid(row=0, column=2)
ttk.Label(root, text='Step', width = 5 ).grid(row=0, column=3)
ttk.Label(root, text='Valid', width = 15 ).grid(row=0, column=4)

rows = []
for r in range(1,16):
    rows.append(row_n(root, r, init_show=r%3 == 0 ))

tk.Button(root, command=show_results, text = '  Show Results  ').grid(column=1, pady = 5)

root.mainloop()
```

This is another approach.  Does this help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I am struggling to integrate it here with my code. Sorry, I am  a newbie in python tkinter GUI. Can I share all of my code ?

Comment: Like all these minimum, maximum and increment textboxes should open only after user checks a checkbutton for that variable.

Comment: I've done an Edit 1 with  a different approach.  I don't think I'll have time to go through all your code and understand the subject your trying to implement.  These two suggestions should give you some ideas.

Comment: How can I access the entries created in the __init__ inside the activation() function so as to disable them?

Comment: Changing `return { 'Min': v_min, 'Max': v_max, 'Inc': v_incr }` to`return { 'Min': v_min, 'Max': v_max, 'Inc': v_incr, 'emin': e_min, 'emax': e_max, 'einc', e_inc  }` will give you access to the actual widget objects via the rows list.   So `row[0]['emin'].config(state='disabled')` will disable the min box on the top row.

Comment: No. It is the original entry that is by default present against a parameter that I'm talking about. The min, max and inc comes into picture only when the checkbutton is ticked. Otherwise, each parameter and has a fixed entry text box which is to be disabled when it is ticked to be chosen as free. i.e. the start and end point of that parameter has to be specified.

Comment: For a better idea, can you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516994/tkinter-how-to-access-widgets-in-init-method-from-another-methods) question?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another suggestion.  Incorporate the Label and Entry in the row-n function.   Include activating / disabling the Entry in the activate function.  The row_n function is executed in a loop through a list of the descriptions you want.

```
import tkinter as tk

row_names = [ "Structure Coefficient(N)", "Chlorophyll Content(Cab) (µg.cm-2)", 
              "Carotenoid content(Car) (µg.cm-2)", "Brown pigment content(Cbrown)(arbitrary units)"]

def row_n(parent, desc, n, init_show = 0 ):
    """ Create one row of the display. """
    # tk.Variables
    v_show = tk.IntVar()
    v_min = tk.StringVar()
    v_max = tk.StringVar()
    v_incr = tk.StringVar()
    v_fixed = tk.StringVar() # New StringVar
    v_message = tk.StringVar()
    v_show.set(init_show)
    v_message.set("OK")

    def do_trace(*args):
        """ Runs every time any of the three Entries change value. 
            Sets the message to the appropriate text.
        """
        lo = to_float(v_min.get())
        hi = to_float(v_max.get())
        inc = to_float(v_incr.get())
        if lo < hi and inc <=hi:
            v_message.set('OK')
        else:
            txt = ''
            if lo >= hi: 
                txt += 'Min >= Max'
            if inc > hi:
                if len(txt): txt += ' & '
                txt += 'Incr > Max'
            v_message.set(txt)

    # Set trace callback for changes to the three StringVars
    v_min.trace('w', do_trace)
    v_max.trace('w', do_trace)
    v_incr.trace('w', do_trace)

    def activation(*args):
        """ Runs when the tickbox changes state """
        if v_show.get():
            e_min.grid(row = n, column = 8)
            e_max.grid(row = n, column = 9)
            e_inc.grid(row = n, column = 10)
            message.grid(row = n, column = 11)
            e_fixed.config(state = 'disabled') # Disable the base Entry

        else:
            e_min.grid_remove()
            e_max.grid_remove()
            e_inc.grid_remove()
            message.grid_remove()
            e_fixed.config(state = 'normal') # Enable the base Entry Widget

    tk.Label(parent, text = desc ).grid(row = r+1, column = 4 ) # Add the desc. Label
    e_fixed = tk.Entry(parent, textvariable = v_fixed) # Add the new Entry widget
    e_fixed.grid(row = r+1, column = 5)
    tk.Checkbutton(parent, 
        text = ' '.format(n), 
        variable = v_show, command = activation ).grid(row = n, column = 6)
    e_min = tk.Entry(parent, width=5, textvariable = v_min)
    e_min.config(font=('Candara', 15))
    e_max =tk.Entry(parent, width=5, textvariable = v_max)
    e_max.config(font=('Candara', 15))
    e_inc = tk.Entry(parent, width=5, textvariable = v_incr)
    e_inc.config(font=('Candara', 15))
    message = tk.Label(parent, width=-15, textvariable = v_message)
    message.config(font=('Candara', 15))
    activation()

    return { 'Min': v_min, 'Max': v_max, 'Inc': v_incr, 'Fixed': v_fixed }
    #  The 'Fixed' field added to the dictionary to return

def print_row(row):
    fmt = 'Min: {}, Max: {}, Inc: {}, Fixed: {}'
    print(fmt.format(
        row['Min'].get(), row['Max'].get(), row['Inc'].get(), row['Fixed'].get() 
    ))

def to_float(txt):

    """ Safely convert any string to a float.  Invalid strings return 0.0 """ 
    try:
        return float(txt)
    except ValueError: 
        return 0.0

# GUI Start
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Validation wth Trace')

# Header Labels
tk.Label(root,text="Min").grid(row=0,column=8,padx=4,pady=4)
tk.Label(root,text="Max").grid(row=0,column=9,padx=4,pady=4)
tk.Label(root,text="Inc").grid(row=0,column=10,padx=4,pady=4)

# Body of rows
rows = []
for r, r_text in enumerate(row_names):
    rows.append(row_n( root, r_text, r+1))

root.mainloop()

print("Strings in the Entry fields")
for r, row in enumerate(rows):
    print('Row: ', r, 'Data:', end=' ')
    print_row(row)
```

HTH.  Seeing your code in the inked question you may prefer to make row_n a class.

Comment: This is about a minimum to show what is required.  You need to take note of the comments on the other question.  By reducing your code to a minimum you may well discover what is wrong yourself.  Your code there doesn't work.  There's no validate method. In your evals 'self' is the tkinter Label not your class. You access files (the image) potential answerers can't see.  You'll get more help if people can copy/paste your code, run it and see the results or the error messages.  All the text fonts etc. aren't relevant to the problem and complicate the code people see.