# Tkinter: How to access widgets in init method from another methods

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I am creating a python GUI for generating a look-up-table. For that, what I need is let the user chose free and fixed parameters. I have done that using checkboxes. When a user ticks a checkbox, that parameter is said to be a free parameter. The user then has to specify the starting point, the ending point, and the step increment in that parameter. There are 15 such parameters. They can be fixed or free.

A fixed parameter can only be specified a value using a entry provided. However, as soon as that parameter is declared to be free, the entry next to it has to be disabled, and the entries specifying the min, max and increment has to be opened.

However, the entries are created in the init method. And the minimums, maximums and increments are created using separate functions. The problem is, how do I access each of that specific entry to be able to disable them when the activation() method of the checkbox is called?

I also want to get the values of entries of the min, max and inc for each free parameter and be able to check the number of free parameters as well.

Here is the code:

```
class GenerateLUT(tk.Frame):
    cnt = 0
    alltextFields = ["N","Cab","Car","Cw","Cm","Cbrown", "rsoil0","LIDFa","LIDFb","TypeLIDF","LAI","hspot","tts","tto","psi" ]
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,width=1000, height=600)
        self.controller = controller


        imgBack = tk.PhotoImage(file='7.gif')
        lblBackGround = tk.Label(self, image=imgBack,width=700, height=600)
        lblBackGround.image = imgBack
        lblBackGround.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        vcmd = (self.register(self.validate), '%P', '%S','%W')

        self.lbl_choose=tk.Label(self,text="Choose free parameters:");self.lbl_choose.grid(row=1,column=7,padx=4,pady=4);self.lbl_choose.config(font=("Georgia", 17))
        self.lbl_min = tk.Label(self,text="Min");self.lbl_min.grid(row=2,column=8,padx=4,pady=4);self.lbl_min.config(font=("Georgia", 17))
        self.lbl_max = tk.Label(self,text="Max");self.lbl_max.grid(row=2,column=9,padx=4,pady=4);self.lbl_max.config(font=("Georgia", 17))
        self.lbl_inc = tk.Label(self,text="Inc");self.lbl_inc.grid(row=2,column=10,padx=4,pady=4);self.lbl_inc.config(font=("Georgia", 17))

        self.lbl_N = tk.Label(self,text="Structure Coefficient(N)",anchor="w",width=40,bg='white'); self.lbl_N.grid(row=3,column=4,padx=4,pady=4);
        self.txt_N = tk.Entry(self,width=10,validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd); self.txt_N.grid(row=3,column=7,padx=4,pady=4);   

        self.lbl_Cab = tk.Label(self,text="Chlorophyll Content(Cab) (µg.cm-2)",anchor="w",width=40); self.lbl_Cab.grid(row=4,column=4,padx=4,pady=4);
        self.txt_Cab = tk.Entry(self,width=10,validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd); self.txt_Cab.grid(row=4,column=7,padx=4,pady=4);        

        self.lbl_Car = tk.Label(self,text="Carotenoid content(Car) (µg.cm-2)",anchor="w",width=40); self.lbl_Car.grid(row=5,column=4,padx=4,pady=4);
        self.txt_Car = tk.Entry(self,width=10,validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd); self.txt_Car.grid(row=5,column=7,padx=4,pady=4);    

        self.lbl_Cbrown = tk.Label(self,text="Brown pigment content(Cbrown)(arbitrary units)",anchor="w",width=40); self.lbl_Cbrown.grid(row=6,column=4,padx=4,pady=4);self.lbl_Cbrown.config(font=("Candara", 15))
        self.txt_Cbrown = tk.Entry(self,width=10,validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd); self.txt_Cbrown.grid(row=6,column=7,padx=4,pady=4);

        self.lbl_Cw = tk.Label(self,text="Equivalent Water Thickness(Cw) (cm)",anchor="w",width=40); self.lbl_Cw.grid(row=7,column=4,padx=4,pady=4);
        self.txt_Cw = tk.Entry(self,width=10,validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd); self.txt_Cw.grid(row=7,column=7,padx=4,pady=4);

        self.lbl_Cm = tk.Label(self,text="Leaf mass per area(Cm) (g.cm-2)",anchor="w",width=40); self.lbl_Cm.grid(row=8,column=4,padx=4,pady=4);
        self.txt_Cm = tk.Entry(self,width=10,validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd); self.txt_Cm.grid(row=8,column=7,padx=4,pady=4);

        self.lbl_LIDFa = tk.Label(self,text="Average leaf slope(LIDFa)",anchor="w",width=40); self.lbl_LIDFa.grid(row=9,column=4,padx=4,pady=4);
        self.txt_LIDFa = tk.Entry(self,width=10,validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd); self.txt_LIDFa.grid(row=9,column=7,padx=4,pady=4);

        self.lbl_LIDFb = tk.Label(self,text="Distribution bimodality(LIDFb)",anchor="w",width=40); self.lbl_LIDFb.grid(row=10,column=4,padx=4,pady=4);
        self.txt_LIDFb = tk.Entry(self,width=10,validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd); self.txt_LIDFb.grid(row=10,column=7,padx=4,pady=4);  

        self.lbl_TypeLIDF = tk.Label(self,text="Type of leaf angle distribution(TypeLIDF)",anchor="w",width=40); self.lbl_TypeLIDF.grid(row=11,column=4,padx=4,pady=4);self.lbl_Cm.config(font=("Candara", 15))
        self.txt_TypeLIDF = tk.Entry(self,width=10,validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd); self.txt_TypeLIDF.grid(row=11,column=7,padx=4,pady=4);

        self.lbl_LAI = tk.Label(self,text="Leaf Area Index(LAI) (m^2/m^2)",anchor="w",width=40); self.lbl_LAI.grid(row=12,column=4,padx=4,pady=4);self.lbl_Cm.config(font=("Candara", 15))
        self.txt_LAI = tk.Entry(self,width=10); self.txt_LAI.grid(row=12,column=7,padx=4,pady=4);

        self.lbl_hspot = tk.Label(self,text="Hot Spot(hspot)",anchor="w",width=40); self.lbl_hspot.grid(row=13,column=4,padx=4,pady=4);self.lbl_Cm.config(font=("Candara", 15))
        self.txt_hspot = tk.Entry(self,width=10,validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd); self.txt_hspot.grid(row=13,column=7,padx=4,pady=4);

        self.lbl_tts = tk.Label(self,text="Solar Zenith Angle(tts) (°)",anchor="w",width=40); self.lbl_tts.grid(row=14,column=4,padx=4,pady=4);
        self.txt_tts = tk.Entry(self,width=10,validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd); self.txt_tts.grid(row=14,column=7,padx=4,pady=4)

        self.lbl_tto = tk.Label(self,text="Observer Zenith Angle(tto) (°)",anchor="w",width=40); self.lbl_tto.grid(row=15,column=4,padx=4,pady=4);
        self.txt_tto = tk.Entry(self,width=10); self.txt_tto.grid(row=15,column=7,padx=4,pady=4)

        self.lbl_psi = tk.Label(self,text="Azimuth(psi) (°)",anchor="w",width=40); self.lbl_psi.grid(row=16,column=4,padx=4,pady=4);
        self.txt_psi = tk.Entry(self,width=10,validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd); self.txt_psi.grid(row=16,column=7,padx=4,pady=4)

        self.lbl_rsoil0 = tk.Label(self,text="rsoil0",anchor="w",width=40); self.lbl_rsoil0.grid(row=17,column=4,padx=4,pady=4);
        self.txt_rsoil0 = tk.Entry(self,width=10,validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd); self.txt_rsoil0.grid(row=17,column=7,padx=4,pady=4)

        self.btn_getLUT = tk.Button(self,text="Generate Look-Up-Table",command=lambda:self.getLUT())
        self.btn_getLUT.grid(row=19,column=7);self.btn_getLUT.config(font=("Georgia", 15))
        self.btn_home = tk.Button(self,text="HOME PAGE",command=lambda:controller.show_frame("StartPage"),font='Verdana',fg='red')
        self.btn_home.grid(row=1,column=2)

        def to_float(txt):

            """ Safely convert any string to a float.  Invalid strings return 0.0 """ 
            try:
                return float(txt)
            except ValueError: 
                return 0.0

        def row_n(parent, n, init_show = 0 ):
            eval("self.txt_N.config(state='disabled')")
            """ Create one row of the display. """
            # tk.Variables
            v_show = tk.IntVar()
            v_min = tk.StringVar()
            v_max = tk.StringVar()
            v_incr = tk.StringVar()
            v_message = tk.StringVar()
            v_show.set(init_show)
            v_message.set("OK")

            def do_trace(*args):
                """ Runs every time any of the three Entries change value. 
                    Sets the message to the appropriate text.
                """
                lo = to_float(v_min.get())
                hi = to_float(v_max.get())
                inc = to_float(v_incr.get())
                if lo < hi and inc <=hi:
                    v_message.set('OK')
                else:
                    txt = ''
                    if lo >= hi: 
                        txt += 'Min >= Max'
                        messagebox.showinfo("Input Error", "Minimum should not be greater than maximum")
                    if inc > hi:
                        if len(txt): txt += ' & '
                        txt += 'Incr > Max'
                        messagebox.showinfo("Input Error", "Increment should not be greater than maximum")
                    v_message.set(txt)

            # Set trace callback for changes to the three StringVars
            v_min.trace('w', do_trace)
            v_max.trace('w', do_trace)
            v_incr.trace('w', do_trace)

            def activation(*args):
                alltextFields = ["N","Cab","Car","Cw","Cm","Cbrown", "rsoil0","LIDFa","LIDFb","TypeLIDF","LAI","hspot","tts","tto","psi" ]
                """ Runs when the tickbox changes state """
                row_str = 3;col_str=8;
                if v_show.get():
                    e_min.grid(row = n, column = 8)
                    e_max.grid(row = n, column = 9)
                    e_inc.grid(row = n, column = 10)
##                    eval("self.txt_" + alltextFields[n-3] + ".config(state='disabled')") # access the entry here
                    message.grid(row = n, column = 11)
                else:
                    e_min.grid_remove()
                    e_max.grid_remove()
                    e_inc.grid_remove()
##                    eval("self.txt_" + alltextFields[n-2] + ".config(state='normal')") # access the entry here
                    message.grid_remove()

            tk.Checkbutton(parent, 
                text = ' '.format(n), 
                variable = v_show, command = activation ).grid(row = n, column = 6)
            e_min = tk.Entry(parent, width=5, textvariable = v_min, validate = 'key', validatecommand=vcmd)
            e_min.config(font=('Candara', 15))
            e_max =tk.Entry(parent, width=5, textvariable = v_max,validate = 'key', validatecommand=vcmd)
            e_max.config(font=('Candara', 15))
            e_inc = tk.Entry(parent, width=5, textvariable = v_incr,validate = 'key', validatecommand=vcmd)
            e_inc.config(font=('Candara', 15))
            message = tk.Label(parent, width=-15, textvariable = v_message)
            message.config(font=('Candara', 15))
            activation()

            return { 'Min': v_min, 'Max': v_max, 'Inc': v_incr }

        self.rows = []
        for r in range(3,18):
            self.rows.append(row_n(self, r, init_show=r%3 == 0 ))

        allWidgets  = ["N","Cab","Car","Cbrown","Cw","Cm","LIDFa","LIDFb", "TypeLIDF","LAI","hspot","tts","tto","psi","rsoil0"]
        for wid in allWidgets:
            widlbl = "self.lbl_" + wid + ".config(font=('Candara', 15))";

            eval(widlbl)

            widtxt = "self.txt_" + wid + ".config(font=('Candara', 15))";
            eval(widtxt)
##            if v_show.get():
##               eval("self.txt_" + alltextFields[n-3] + ".config(state='disabled')")
```

The error I get is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROSAIL_5B_Fortran\PROSAIL_5B_FORTRAN\PROSAIL_val.py", line 620, in <module>
    app = PROSAIL()
  File "C:\PROSAIL_5B_Fortran\PROSAIL_5B_FORTRAN\PROSAIL_val.py", line 27, in __init__
    frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
  File "C:\PROSAIL_5B_Fortran\PROSAIL_5B_FORTRAN\PROSAIL_val.py", line 378, in __init__
    self.rows.append(row_n(self, r, init_show=r%3 == 0 ))
  File "C:\PROSAIL_5B_Fortran\PROSAIL_5B_FORTRAN\PROSAIL_val.py", line 303, in row_n
    eval("self.txt_N.config(state='disabled')")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: You've posted way too much code. Please try to [edit] your question and reduce the code down to a [mcve].

Comment: Edited my code.. Any help now?

Comment: You've got more than a dozen labels and other widgets. Do you really need all of those widgets to reproduce this error? There are also functions in the code that don't seem necessary. The goal is to reduce this code to a _minimum_. This will help you to understand the root cause of the problem.

Comment: I have put all these to provide the exact information about my requirement. Since there are 15 different parameters, there is going to be 15 entries for them. And I need to access each of them when the checkbutton next to it is ticked. The functions are nested functions

Comment: why are you using `eval`? It almost never is the right solution. Are you open to solutions that remove all uses of `eval`?

Comment: Yes.. As long as it solves my problem

Comment: Also, why are you nesting all of your functions inside your `__init__` rather than making them proper methods?

Comment: I am a newbie with tkinter gui programming. I have  implemented this code after looking up from various sources. I can not put up a complete optimized code. I am not sure what this has to do with the question I posted